# jQuery-Limiting Amount of Animations

Tags: jquery

I am creating a simple webpage as part of my computer assignment and I decided to include some jQuery in it. Its very simple jQuery and is listed below:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    height: 410,
    width: 500,
    resizeable: true,
    });
$('#credits').hide();
$('#doctor_seuss_info').hide();
$('#title').hover(function() {
    $('#credits').show('slow')
    });
$('#title').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#credits').hide('slow');
    });
$('#doctor_seuss_title').hover(function(){
    $('#doctor_seuss_info').show('slow');
    });
$('#doctor_seuss_title').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#doctor_seuss_info').hide('slow');
    });
$('#other_poems').accordion();
$('#doctor_seuss_fish').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({'marginLeft' : '-60em'}, 5000);
    });
});
```

The problem that I have is that the website is sort of hard to navigate because everything will move around if you move your mouse too fast. How would I go about adding a limit on how many times an object will move?

Comment: maybe you are just looking for `.stop()`

Answer (score 0):

You should try looking into hoverIntent: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

This seems like the perfect solution you're looking for because it'll only trigger the function if the mouse has hovered over for a given time.

Answer (score 0):

Should be better:

*hover beeing a shorthand for mouseenter/mouseleave, your code was not working as you expect it*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 410,
        width: 500,
        resizeable: true,
    });
    $('#credits, #doctor_seuss_info').hide();
    $('#title').hover(function () {
        $('#credits').stop().toggle('slow')
    });

    $('#doctor_seuss_title').hover(function () {
        $('#doctor_seuss_info').stop().toggle('slow');
    });

    $('#other_poems').accordion();
    $('#doctor_seuss_fish').click(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            'marginLeft': '-60em'
        }, 5000);
    });
});
```